Flutter build fails on android, but no obvious error message
I'm attempting to build my app after recently upgrading the versions of flutter and the various packages that are imported.  This works fine for the iOS emulator, but not for running on android.  I am consistently getting failures in the build, but I cannot see an obvious error message to indicate what's going wrong.  Are you able to offer me some pointers?
Build output here:
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 6a in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/neill.bowler/Development/flutter/bin/flutter''

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

(I have set --stacktrace and --debug in my gradle compiler options in android studio, but that doesn't seem to have worked)
android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '56'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '56'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.0.8775105"

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "mycompany.christianmeditation"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        versionCode 61
        versionName "61"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
            }
        }
    }

//    compileOptions {
//        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
//        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
//        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.5.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'  //with androidx libraries
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.1.2'
//    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
//    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
}

// apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mycompany.christianmeditation">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <application
        android:label="Reflect"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true" tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <queries>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

And finally flutter doctor output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 13.6.9 22G830 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/neill.bowler/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (6 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/neill.bowler/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915915-b509.11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15C500b
    • CocoaPods version 1.14.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915915-b509.11)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/neill.bowler/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (4 available)            
    • Pixel 6a (mobile)                   • 2A241JEGR07300                       • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34)
    • iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • E2A44B1A-D1EC-479F-AFD3-11E1714C9996 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                     • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.6.9 22G830 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)                        • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.70

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Many thanks!

What happens if you manually execute on command-line/Users/neill.bowler/Development/flutter/bin/flutter? Does this work, do you see the output? Based on the path you seem to use MacOS, what version?

Yes, /Users/neill.bowler/Development/flutter/bin/flutter is where my flutter build is, and this runs fine.  I'm using a mac, and given your comment I upgrade to mocOS Ventura 13.7.  I've now got an incompatibility between my java and gradle versions which is causing me a headache.  The recent flutter update required various changes to the gradle files, so my expectation is that there's something in there which is causing my original error.

Simply install the jre/jdk version you need and use it. Simply ignore the one that comes with MacOS.

I have managed to solve my own problem.  I've done three things, and in combination they seem to have worked.

Take a newer project, and copy the settings from android/build.gradle and android/app/build.gradle across to the existing project. Updated files pasted below for information.
The upgrade switched me to a newer version of JAVA (which then required an updated gradle version, which led to a bunch of problems).  I forced the use of an older version of JAVA by setting JAVA_HOME, via: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home.
I was then having a lot of problems with dexing (file size shrinking).  This was solved by updating the minimum android SDK from 21 to 24.

I have been using flutter run from the command line.  Using flutter -v -d "Pixel 6a" run was sometimes very helpful, sometimes cluttered the screen.  Many thanks to Robert for the suggestions.
Updated android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Updated android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "62"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "62"
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace = "mycompany.christianmeditation"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.bible_in_a_year"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties["keyAlias"]
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties["keyPassword"]
            storeFile = keystoreProperties["storeFile"] ? file(keystoreProperties["storeFile"]) : null
            storePassword = keystoreProperties["storePassword"]
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"  //with androidx libraries
    coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4"
}

